# Use the integral test to prove convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, limits, functions

I have done this problem, i'm just for some confirmation if it's correct.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$$
Consider the function $f : [1,\infty)\to[0,\infty),  f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$. The function is monotone decreasing. We calculate the integral, $$\int^N_1f(x)dx=\int^N_1\frac{1}{x^2}dx=\int^N_1x^{-2}dx$$
$$\frac{x^{-1}}{-1}|^{x=N}_{x=1}=-1(N^{-1}-1)$$
We have $$\lim_{N\to\infty}-1(N^{-1}-1) = -1\lim_{N\to\infty}(\frac{1}{N}-1
)=1<\infty$$
Hence by the integral test, the series converges.

Is this correct?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have "$f(x)= \frac{1}{n^2}$" where you should have $f(x)= \frac{1}{x^2}$ but other than that obvious typo, yes, this is correct.

Comment: edited now haha, thank you very much!!

Comment: You should actually try to find for what values of $p$ the following integral is convergent: $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^p}dx$. You can use this result for future problems related to yours...

Comment: can you find a bound for $\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{N^2} \ \ - \int_1^{N+1} \frac{1}{x^2} dx$ ?

Comment: A simpler argument is to show that $\frac 1{n^2}<\int_{n-1}^n\frac 1{x^2}dx$. Omitting the first term since the integral diverges leads to $\sum_{n=2}^N\frac 1{n^2}<\int_1^N\frac 1{x^2}dx$.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this correct? Thank you in advance.

Yes, this is very much correct. Although, if you might be interested, we can prove this in general for any $p>1$ for the sum $\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{1}{n^p}$ through the use of the integral test.
\begin{align}
\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^p}\mathrm{d}x&=\left[\frac{x^{1-p}}{1-p}\right]_1^{\infty}\\
&=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{t^{1-p}}{1-p}-\frac{1}{1-p}
\end{align}
For $p>1$ the quantity $1-p<0$ therefore $t^{1-p}\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$ therefore $$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^p}\mathrm{d}x=-\frac{1}{1-p}\text{ for }p>1$$
This is a finite value $\forall p>1$ thus we can say that because this improper integral converges with the condition we listed, then the sum
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^p}$$
converges too (if and only if $p>1$).